# How do you import GeoTools into an existing project in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, geotools

I have an existing project that was not built using Maven, and I would like to import the GeoTools library.

From the GeoTools website, the startup guide for Intellij involves creating a Maven project and modifying the pom file. But my project already exists and isn't a Maven project so it doesn't have a pom file.

I tried downloading all of the jar files for GeoTools 18.3 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/geotools/files/GeoTools%2018%20Releases/18.3/ and placing them into my lib folder, but I was still unable to import from com.geotools.

I tried adding GeoTools using the "Download Library from Maven Repository" feature, but searching "GeoTools" results in over 100 results from non-official sources, so I am unsure if any of them are what I'm looking for.

How do I import GeoTools into my project?

Answer (score 0):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) is a not for profit org so you need to import from `org.geotools` not `com.geotools`.

If you insist on not using Maven to manage your dependencies (and I don't recommend this approach) the you can tyr following the [NetBeans instructions](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/netbeans.html#maven-alternative) which should apply to intelliJ too. The trick is to remove 3 of the 4 epsg jars otherwise they fight.